# Git. Keep stable and dev versions of project

Tags: git

I want two versions of project: `stable` and `dev`.
It should look like:

```
/home/me/proj/stable
/home/me/proj/dev
```

I want do some changes on `dev` version and then bring them to `stable`.

How I solve the task:

1) Create project in `dev` directory

2) `git clone dev stable`

3) On every change in `dev`:

```
cd /home/me/proj/dev
git add .
git commit -m 'fixes'
cd ../stable
git pull
```

It works fine, but when I delete some files from `dev`, then do `pull`, those files are still in `stable`. I don't want them there. I want `stable` to be full copy of `dev`.

Comment: This is what branches are for. Why don't you want to use them?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs he is, although disguised as clones.

Comment: If both clones are checking out master then they are not using branches.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Because my project is a website. `stable` is for users, `dev` is for me. Both should be online at the one time

Comment: That's still what branches are for.

Comment: @imkost Then you should use branches.

Comment: @KyleStrand I don't know how make branches of one project in different folders. Will you explain?

Comment: @imkost When you removed the files from dev, did you use `git rm` or otherwise add the removals to the git index?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs, no, I didn't do it

Comment: @imkost Then you did not remove them from git and git is behaving properly. You should read the manpage for [git-rm](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm).

Comment: @ReinHenrichs, reading right now) Thank you

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I'll let you have it, but I will have it noted that I think it's sad that people aren't distinguishing more between "facts" and "convention". What you describe is _convention_. However, the _ref names_ have zero influence on the picture. `refs/heads/master` is a different branch from `refs/remote/origin/master` and they do not actually even **need** to have any commits in common. They are branches. (In a way, branches don't exist in git. There are just refs and some namespaces of them (refs, tags etc.))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you might try using GIT with two branches, dev and stable, and by merging branches to keep your two 'versions' in sync.  As:

```
$ mkdir /home/me/proj; cd /home/me/proj
$ git init
$ echo 'README' > README; git add README; git commit -m 'README'
$ git branch stable
$ git checkout -b dev

# do your development
$ git commit <stuff>

# now bring the stuff to <stable>
$ git checkout stable
$ git merge dev
```

Note: files deleted in `dev` will disappear in `stable` upon the above merge.

```
# back to dev for more development
$ git checkout dev
```

If you need to deploy the stable version somewhere, use

```
$ cd <parent dir for deploy>
$ git clone /home/me/proj --branch stable
```

Comment: Nice! I've just tried it. It works so great) And it is more convenient, then having folders instead of branches. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for

```
git clean -df .
```

(although, if the deletions are versioned, then it should be automatic unless there were local changes)

To make sure deletions are tracked, do

```
git add -A .
```

instead of just

```
git commit -am '........'
```